# Do a PUT request via proxy using Node JS and request package

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, rest, request

I have a webapp (using AngularJS) which runs on a webserver on my local computer. I need to do AJAX REST requests using my NodeJS server, and proxy that to another server off-site. All the `GET` requests are going through fine using the [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) package. But my puts come through with an empty body.

The `GET` request is piped using this:

```
$request.get(apiUrl+req.url).pipe(res);
```

And it works fine.

And my empty `PUT` request looks like this:

```
$request.put(apiUrl+req.url).pipe(req);
```

I have verified that the `PUT` request is sent to the desired REST API using Wireshark. Somehow I can't figure out how the piping should be done I think. I get answer from the REST server that my body can't be `null`.

Any clues? I guess this is really simple but the documentation on the request package isn't really satisfying I think.

Whole code is here, which the node server checks if we are doing using the address /api

```
 if(runAsProxy && req.url.indexOf('/api') === 0){
  console.log("this is /api")
  if(req.method ==="PUT"){
     console.log("PUT")
     $request.put(apiUrl+req.url).pipe(res);
     console.log("body: ",req.body)
  }

  else if(req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD'){
     $request.get(apiUrl+req.url).pipe(res);

  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not sending any data with your `PUT`, since the server responds with a message that your body cannot be `null`.
Since you are proxying, try piping your original request through the API to the response as documented at https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming

```
req.pipe($request(apiUrl + req.url)).pipe(res)
```

Comment: I've tried that. That line does work with the GET requests, but not with the PUT requests. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try not relying on the pipe magic and setting up your request manually with headers and request body like https://github.com/mikeal/request#examples
Sometimes the naive piping approach leaves over headers that confuse the API or has problems sending over the data correctly. I also once built a proxy with `request`, and the piping - while elegant - caused a lot of trouble.

Comment: does your client put have a body?

Comment: Yes, the NodeJS server is capable of presenting the req.body, and it is the desired body. However, I'm not able to build my own request, help anyone?